# Split byte array

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4

I am currently working on a small personal project which allows a user to drag a list item from a QListWidget in PyQt4 onto a label which opens up a message dialogue. You will see that `selected` comes produces both the title and the link in both instances. How can I just access the individual elements? I am aiming to achieve the first element (title) in the dialog header which is the 2nd parameter of the about() method and show the second part of the bytearray (link) in the main dialog box.

```
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        data = event.mimeData()
        bstream = data.retrieveData("application/x-feed", QtCore.QVariant.ByteArray)
        selected = pickle.loads(bstream.toByteArray())
        event.accept()
        QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, str(selected),
""" %s """ % str(selected)
)
```

**EDIT**

```
class base(object):
    def __init__(self, name, link):
        self.name = name
        self.link = link

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s\n%s" % (self.name, self.link)
```

**Error: TypeError 'base' does not support indexing**

Background reading so far: 
http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QMimeData.html
https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `pickle.loads` returns a tuple, then you may use this syntax:

```
(title,link) = pickle.loads(bstream.toByteArray())
```

Or

```
selected = pickle.loads(bstream.toByteArray())
title = selected[0]
link = selected[1]
```

**EDIT**

I initially thought `pickle.loads` returned a tuple but it returns an `base` object with two attributes so you just need to access this attributes (remember there are not private attributes in Python):

```
selected = pickle.loads(bstream.toByteArray())
title = selected.name
link = selected.link
```

Comment: Thanks so much! However, I am getting this error: Error: TypeError 'base' does not support indexing - I have added in the object in question

Comment: I initially thought `pickle.loads` returned a tuple but it returns an object with two attributes. You should access to them directly `selected.name`